# Should We Change the Specific Words Tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We seem to have duplicate tags. One is the [specific-words](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-words) and the other is [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary). Why do we have both? Should we merge them, and if so, which one is merged into the other?

Comment: It is possible to create tag synonyms without any moderator intervention in [the tag synonym menu](http://latin.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). Someone has to propose the synonym and then others can vote on it. But both proposing and voting require a certain score in that tag (and going to the tag synonym page), so this is unlikely to work well at our small site for almost any tag. Discussing at meta and then having a moderator do it is the best choice for the time being.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am in favor of merging [specific-words](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-words) into [vocabulary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary). The latter fully encompasses the former, while allowing for some broader wiggle room (as evidenced [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why) and [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/what-do-animals-say-in-classical-latin)). Moreover, "vocabulary" is a clear indication of what the tag should do, whereas "specific words" is clunky and seems to indicate one single word per question (whereas perhaps multiple words ought to be discussed instead).

Comment: I agree. In fact, I have grown to dislike the tag [tag:specific-words] as it doesn't really help explain what the question is about. I like [tag:vocabulary] much better.

Comment: I, too, agree. Since this answers gets support without objection, I have merged the tags as suggested.

Comment: @Cerberus Probably could have waited another day or two, but imo, the sooner "specific-words" is gone, the better.